# What is the use of current inspection profile in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, project, inspection

I was working on a project in android studio and suddenly I found a man type logo [image: this]

I hover my mouse on in for a second then it shows me

```
Current Inspection profile: Project default.
Click to configure highlightening for the file.
```

When i clicked on this button it shows me [image: this]

**Now I want to know what is the use of this option or is this is important or not?**

It may can be stupid question but I asked this question just to increase my own knowledge becuse this option seems bit important

Thanks In advance!

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

This has little to do with [code inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-inspection.html), but one can only define what is being highlighted. One could call it the visual representation of the inspection results, as it clearly read "highlighting level". This option only is of use, when you have to work with an old crappy computer, but rather irrelevant on current hardware.

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggest, it inspects your code for issues, errors, incompatibility etc. and may  recommends better options. If your system is low on resources (RAM, Battery, CPU) you can select None and also you can choose the PowerSave mode.